# BreakPoints Are not working in Swift in Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode6.3

In my project I have both objective c and Swift classes. I want to do debugging in objective c breakpoints are working whereas in Swift breakpoints are not working so it very difficult to debug.

Note : I am integrating my objective c project in my swift project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the piece of code with breakpoints in it definitely being executed?

Comment: yes I am printing values also

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I have the same problem in Xcode9.4...

Answer (score 0):

Have you turned it on?

Attached the arrow to the setting
[image]

Comment: Its there, if its not there then breakpoints in objective c also will not work right?